# Laravel: Retrieve data from foreign key

Tags: laravel, eloquent

I'm having problems with a foreign key, specifically I want to get the table data using a foreign key, my code looks like.

```
// Migration foo
public function up()
{
    Schema::create('foo', function(Blueprint $table)
    {
        // Default index laravel uses.
        $table->increments('id');

        $table->integer('bar_id')->unsigned();
        $table->text('fake_date')

        // Default timestamps
        $table->timestamps();

        // Foreign Key
        $table->foreign('bar_id')->references('id')->on('bars')->onDelete('cascade')->onUpdate('cascade');
    });
}

public function down()
{
    Schema::drop('foo');
}

// Migration bar
public function up()
{
    Schema::create('bar', function(Blueprint $table)
    {
        // Default index laravel uses.
        $table->increments('id');
        $table->string('name'); // I want to retrieve this data
    });
}

public function down()
{
    Schema::drop('bar');
}
```

My foo model:

```
class Record extends \Eloquent {
    protected $table = 'foo';

    public function bar()
    {
        return $this->belongsTo('Bar');
    }
}
```

My bar model:

```
public function foo()
{
    return $this->hasMany('Foo');
}
}
```

So far I want to just print the value of 'name' inside table bar in a view which uses foo.
I have a view called inside the route foo called show.blade.php and I've tried      {{ $foo->bar()->name }} and I'm getting a syntax error: Call to undefined method Illuminate\Database\Query\Builder::patients()

For clarification I'm trying to post the value of the value name in bar. So I have a blade file that has

```
// views/plays/show.blade.php
<p> {{$foo->bar()->name }} </p>
```

Comment: perhaps you can add your actual code that is causing the error

Comment: the    {{ $foo->bar()->name }} is causing the error

Comment: and what is $foo. can you paste the actual relevant code ?

Comment: Terribly sorry, I was trying to figure out how to escape html on SO, foo refers to the first table which has a foreign key referencing table bar. The view show.blade.php is just trying to print the value of bar given its ID.

Answer (score 0):

in controller where you pass the value of orders,

```
$foos=Foo::with('bar')->where(your_condition)->get();
```

then access the value in blade

```
@foreach($foos as $foo)
                       <p>{{ $foo->bar->name }}</p>
 @endforeach
```

Answer (score -1):

Found the solution, wrong syntax you don't need () ahead of bar, to post the name you simply do {{ $foo->bar->name }}